# On C# WinForm ListBox how to clear the selection of multiple items with a key pressed?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, multipleselection

I'm trying to clear the selection of all items in a WinFom ListBox when the escape key is pressed.

I created a KeyPress event handler in order to catch the event. It works when only one item is selected, but when multiple items are selected the event never triggers, . Any idea of what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Here I attached my event handler:

```
private void EscapeKeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
            {
                switch (sender.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(sender, null).ToString())
                {
                    case "LineLB":
                        LineLB.ClearSelected();
                        break;
                    case "ApplicationLB":
                        ApplicationLB.ClearSelected();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
```

--20150526--

Thanks all you guys for your comments and suggestions. It was a focus problem as some of you mentioned before. I add a line of code in the SelectedIndexChange event handler, and here the comparison.

Before

```
private void LineLB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (LineLB.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
                ClearControlsFromPanel(PanelUser);
            else{
                   ...
```

After

```
    private void LineLB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (LineLB.SelectedItems.Count > 1){
                ClearControlsFromPanel(PanelLine);
                LineLB.Focus();
            }
            else{
                   ...
```

Comment: I created a sample WinForm program  with the keypress event attached to the listbox itself. My example works just fine... According to the documentation, ClearSelected() is supposed to clear all selected items (.NET 4.5 VS 2013 here). Maybe some other handler is stealing your EscapeKeyPressed handler

Comment: I have also tried your solution and works fine.  I have a sneaky feeling you are having a focus issue as opposed to a key press issue, when you press the ESC key does your list box have focus?  Which listbox is your keypress event wired to?

Comment: Helo Ruskin, thanks for your comments. You were totally right, I was losing the focus on the SelectedIndexChanged event when I detect more than one selected items. I solved it just adding the ListBox.Focus();

Answer (score 0):

this is due to focus out with one ListBox when you working with other ListBox, you need to work with KeyPress event of the Form instead of ListBox.